# Document Interaction Controller

Tags: ios, sandbox, uidocumentinteraction

My app is supposed to be able to read and edit PDF, DOC and TXT file formats, so I decided to use another application (let me name it as app2) to open and edit files from my application.

But when I save the file in app2, file gets saved into sandbox of the app2. Is it possible to make app2 save files into my application's sandbox?

Comment: Not without re-opening it in the original app...

Answer (score 1):

[The application sandbox](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/TheiOSEnvironment/TheiOSEnvironment.html) secures all of the files for that application... So unless you've gotten some sort of jailbroken phone you're basically going to have 1 app with 1 sandbox (i.e. 1 set of files).  However, there are certain dependencies you can take advantage of from within your app. (e.g. you can do things like open a PDF using a WebView if you have iBooks or a PDF reader installed on the phone, or boot the user off to Safari to open a web link)